# typo3: Change style of h2 header

Tags: html, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm still fiddling with typo3 (Version: 6.2.15) and I have gotten none of the code I found on the net to work. What I want to do, is define that a header is always converted into:

```
<h2 class="title-divider">
  <span> {HEADERTEXT} <span class="de-em"></span></span>
  <small>{SUBHEADER}</small>
</h2>
```

What I tried:

Based on this website: https://axelerant.com/change-typo3-header-layout-options/

I was able to add new Header types, but when I use the code for the styling from this website, my header just disappears...

I also tried to use the code that was published at http://www.typo3-addict.com/2010/03/a-custom-header-layout/ but first, it doesn't work for me, and second I don't really get how I could change it to display the subheader.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or even better give me a code example that explains the concept that is followed, since it seems to be a misunderstanding of the concept.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, a couple of ours into the documentation and I have found a solution that works:

I added

```
stdheader.10.2 = COA
    stdheader.10.2 {
        setCurrent {
            field = header
            htmlSpecialChars = 1
        }
        key {
            field = header_layout
            ifEmpty = {$content.defaultHeaderType}
            ifEmpty.override.data = register: defaultHeaderType
        }
        10 = TEXT
        10.current = 1
        20 = TEXT
        20 {
            field = subheader
            stdWrap.noTrimWrap = | <span class="de-em"></span></span><small>|</small>|
            stdWrap.required = 1
            field.value = 
        }

        stdWrap.dataWrap = <h2 class="title-divider">|</h2>
        typolink.parameter.field = header_link
        stdWrap.required = 1
}
stdheader.20.2 = COA
stdheader.20.2 {
        wrap = <span style="display: none" class="hiddensubheader">|</span>
}
```

to the lib element in setup.ts.

Comment: All default CE like header, text, text + images are from "css_styled_content" core extension. You can see typoscript here typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/static and you can modify it into your TS template.